# How to encode a url that supplies a path to NancyFX

Tags: c#, urlencode, nancy

I have a module with the following GET API:

`Get["/filesignature/{relativePath}"] = GetFileSignature;`

And I attempt to use WebClient.DownloadData with the following:

```
var myPath = @"mydirectory\myfile.exe";
client.DownloadData("filesignature/" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myPath));
```

I can see it gets encoded to `filesignature/mydirectory%5cmyfile.exe`, so that looks right.

However, I'm getting returned 404.  I attempted to do this in a browser, and it's the same.  When I remove the `%5c`, my breakpoint in the call is reached.  So it seems to be an issue with the backslash encoding.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't find an exact solution to my problem.  But instead I use WebClient's Query property and set the name/values properly there.  No encoding needed then.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1280

To save you the suspense, final comment:

> This is unsolveable .. all framework suffer from this on all platforms

Another quote:

> a request to "foo/bar%2fbaz" will resolve to route "foo/{bar}/baz",
>   despite the "/" having been encoded (and should therefore not be
>   treated as a path separator).

Appears the same thing happens to backslash (%5c).

Possible workarounds:

- Use querystring instead
- Replace % with ! in URL, then back again on the server (yuk)
- ...?